# Gnome freezes and crashed on Ubuntu 18.04.4LTS randomly

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gnome-shell, crash

I recently installed ubuntu18.04LTS alongside windows 10 on my laptop.Recently(after a system update)the gnome started to crash randomly.First I recognized this while I was playing some games on Wine,as the game stopped responding to any action,such as keydown or mousemove.Then it happed when using VLC,the interface appears,but the video not.When I used killall vlc,it didn't work.The interface keeped until next boot.Now I use firefox to browse the web and it can crash without notification——the sidebar froze and the title bar of all the windows disappered so I actally cannot contrl them.And terminal not working sometimes when freeze(using Ctrl+Alt+T donnot work)

I don't use any kind of extension of gnome .

My hardware:intel 8265U | graphic card-nvidia Geforce MX250（Actally not using,I always use the intel UHD620 inside the cpu) | teamgroup 16GB DDR4

this is the log file from last crash./var/log/apport.log

```
ERROR: apport (pid 8618) Mon May 18 03:08:13 2020: called for pid 1558, signal 6, core limit 18446744073709551615, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 8618) Mon May 18 03:08:13 2020: ignoring implausibly big core limit, treating as unlimited
ERROR: apport (pid 8618) Mon May 18 03:08:13 2020: executable: /usr/bin/Xwayland (command line "/usr/bin/Xwayland :1024 -rootless -terminate -accessx -core -listen 4 -listen 5 -displayfd 6")
ERROR: apport (pid 8618) Mon May 18 03:08:13 2020: debug: session gdbus call: (true,)

ERROR: apport (pid 8618) Mon May 18 03:08:13 2020: apport: report /var/crash/_usr_bin_Xwayland.121.crash already exists and unseen, doing nothing to avoid disk usage DoS
~
```

here is some info in _usr_bin_Xwayland.121.crash(too long to post all)

```
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
CurrentDesktop: GNOME-Greeter:GNOME
Date: Thu May 14 16:56:28 2020
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 18.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/Xwayland
ExecutableTimestamp: 1571667977
ProcCmdline: /usr/bin/Xwayland :1024 -rootless -terminate -accessx -core -listen 4 -listen 5 -displayfd 6
ProcCwd: /var/lib/gdm3
ProcEnviron:
 LANGUAGE=zh_CN:zh
 PATH=(custom, no user)
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set>
 LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
 SHELL=/bin/false
ProcMaps:
 55746838f000-5574685b3000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 134521                     /usr/bin/Xwayland
 5574687b2000-5574687b8000 r--p 00223000 08:08 134521                     /usr/bin/Xwayland
 5574687b8000-5574687c0000 rw-p 00229000 08:08 134521                     /usr/bin/Xwayland
 5574687c0000-5574687e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 55746a1dd000-55746a778000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
 7f8854000000-7f8854021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f8854021000-7f8858000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f8858000000-7f8858021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 

...

ProcStatus:
 Name:  Xwayland
 Umask: 0002
 State: S (sleeping)
 Tgid:  1552
 Ngid:  0
 Pid:   1552
 PPid:  1
 TracerPid: 0
 Uid:   121 121 121 121
 Gid:   125 125 125 125
 FDSize:    64
 Groups:    125 
 NStgid:    1552
 NSpid: 1552
 NSpgid:    1453
 NSsid: 1453
 VmPeak:     1019500 kB
 VmSize:      958016 kB
 VmLck:        0 kB
 VmPin:        0 kB
 VmHWM:    58852 kB
 VmRSS:    58852 kB
 RssAnon:      15720 kB
 RssFile:      43076 kB
 RssShmem:        56 kB
 VmData:       90712 kB
 VmStk:      132 kB
 VmExe:     2192 kB
 VmLib:   132116 kB
 VmPTE:      644 kB
 VmSwap:           0 kB
 HugetlbPages:         0 kB
 CoreDumping:   1
 THP_enabled:   1
 Threads:   10
 SigQ:  0/63391
 SigPnd:    0000000000000000
 ShdPnd:    0000000000000000
 SigBlk:    000000000a392000
 SigIgn:    0000000000001000
 SigCgt:    00000001c18064cf
 CapInh:    0000000000000000
 CapPrm:    0000000000000000
 CapEff:    0000000000000000
 CapBnd:    0000003fffffffff
 CapAmb:    0000000000000000
 NoNewPrivs:    0
 Seccomp:   0
 Speculation_Store_Bypass:  thread vulnerable
 Cpus_allowed:  ff
 Cpus_allowed_list: 0-7
 Mems_allowed:  00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000001
 Mems_allowed_list: 0
 voluntary_ctxt_switches:   892
 nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:    6
Signal: 6
Uname: Linux 5.3.0-53-generic x86_64
UserGroups: 
_LogindSession: c1
CoreDump: base64
 H4sICAAAAAAC/0NvcmVEdW1wAA==
```

And one important point,thought it happens randomly,it will be more often when the cpu useage is high,such as opening a big file,slide quickly on the page,or gaming.

Comment: Have you tested if this happens with Xorg(usually default)?  Wayland is suppose to be newer and better, but I don't think it is all the way there yet.  If it happens on Xorg also, something else is going on.

Comment: Thank you so much.I tried Xorg and  it truned out working well.I tested the game,the game still crashes（maybe the bug of wine or the game itself,sad),but this time I can use Super+D and Crtl+Alt+T.The popup window of"force quit" also shows.

Comment: I went into /var/crash and I found a crash log of _italic_gnome-shell_italic_ when the first crash happens on May 14.Here is it.

Comment: roblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
CurrentDesktop: GNOME-Greeter:GNOME
Date: Thu May 14 16:56:10 2020
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 18.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/gnome-shell
ExecutableTimestamp: 1571973788
ProcCmdline: /usr/bin/gnome-shell
ProcCwd: /var/lib/gdm3
ProcEnviron:
 LANGUAGE=zh_CN:zh
 PATH=(custom, no user)
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set>
 LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
 SHELL=/bin/falseProcStatus:
 Name:  gnome-shell
 Umask: 0002
 State: S (sleeping)
 Tgid:  1524
 Ngid:  0
 Pid:   1524
 PPid:  1460
 TracerPid:     0
 Uid:   121     121     121     121
 Gid:   125     125     125    125

Comment: Depending on the game, they can require quite a bit of resources.  Add in using wine for it, you might need full power of GPU also.  Will need someone else to check your Gnome problem.

Comment: <p>I use 480p resolution so it won't have this kind of problem;;however,I guess wine has some confilcts with it,because I lost all my saved points:( </p>I switched gnome from using Wayland to using Xorg,for now it works fine. Maybe in the future I will try to use Unity of Xfce,not now(today I tried Xfce,it has some problem with Xorg.I lost my libinput,cannot enter the system,and finally fixed it under recovery mode)

Comment: Know that unity and gnome play very well together if installed.  Had some problems with gnome when it came out in 18.04,  but too lazy to fix and liked unity better.  Should also check google for ubuntu and your cpu, seems like you are not the only one

Comment: My idea for switching to Xorg was more for testing, than answer.  Think it better if you placed the answer for your problem.

Comment: Reinstalled wine and the game did't crash more.Maybe it's first caused by some confilct of wine(using full screen to play game)_then the gnome using Wayland crashed,and cannot restart itsellf until next boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to Xorg (should be the default,but not on my machine),and continued to using gnome.Here,for three days,no more crashes or bugs happend.Seeming like it's the problem of wayland,it can't work properly when some programs crashed(such as wine)
Answer closed.Special thanks for @crip659,he is wise and humble.